# How to group by date and get all in and out time in?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get all in/out event in row .My table look like this;

Trnevents:

```
 emp_id EVENTID     DT
 4176   3   2019-04-09 15:34:12.000
 4176   1   2019-04-09 08:55:13.000
 4176   3   2019-04-08 16:08:32.000
 4176   2   2019-04-08 15:08:18.000
 4176   1   2019-04-08 14:41:37.000
 4176   0   2019-04-08 08:45:13.000
```

I tried below query but not satisfied with that output

```
 select
t.emp_reader_id as empId,B.emp_name, cast(max(DT) as date) as Belongs_to,B.areaname as POINTID,
 max(iif(EVENTID = 0, DT, null)) as F1, max(iif(EVENTID = 1, DT, null)) as F2, max(iif(EVENTID = 2, DT, null)) as F3, max(iif(EVENTID = 3, DT, null)) as F4,
  format(dateadd(ss,Datediff(second,max(iif(EVENTID = 0, DT, null)),max(iif(EVENTID = 3, DT, null))),0),'HH:mm') as Worked from (   
select
    *, grp = sum(iif(EVENTID = 0, 3, 0) ) over (partition by emp_reader_id order by DT)
from        Trnevents ) t inner join employee B on t.emp_reader_id=B.emp_reader_id where b.emp_reader_id=4176
   group by t.emp_reader_id,t.grp,B.emp_name,t.Belongs_to,B.areaname
                  order by emp_reader_id,t.Belongs_to,F1,F2 asc
```

Expected out be like:

```
  emp_id       dt          f1        f2       f3      f4     hours
  4176     2019-04-08     08:45     14:41   15:08    16:08   06:41
  4176     2019-04-08     08:55       -        -       15:34   06:39
```

I need exactly output as mentioned above.Thanks in advance

> Eventid:

0 as F1,
1 as F2,
2 as F3,
3 as F4

Comment: What is the requirement?  Just saying I need this does not help because we need to know if you are simplifying data for example:  Is f1 really the first time for the date and f4 the last time for the date.  And then f2/f3 are OPTIONALLY the middle times?  or is it more open ended data, i.e. you could have 5+ rows for the day too.

Comment: @SaadAhmad yes >Eventid:0 as F1 as first in,1 as F2,2 as F3,3 as F4  as last out

Comment: search for `PIVOT`

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis kindly help me

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: SELECT  emp_reader_id,   dt,
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]  
FROM  
(SELECT emp_reader_id, dt,EVENTID
    FROM trnevents where emp_reader_id=4176) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
AVG(eventid)  
FOR eventid IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])  
) AS PivotTable;   is it correct? @GeorgeMenoutis

Answer (score 1):

below code snippet should be of help:

```
SELECT emp_id,day,
TO_CHaR(to_date(F1,'HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI') F1,
TO_CHaR(to_date(F2,'HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI') F2,
TO_CHaR(to_date(F3,'HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI') F3,
TO_CHaR(to_date(F4,'HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI') F4  FROM (
  SELECT emp_id,event_id,to_char(DT,'DD-MON-YYYY') day ,to_number(replace(to_char(DT,'HH24:MI'),':','.'),'99.99') dt_time from sample_event a

)
PIVOT (
  avg(dt_time)
  FOR event_id in (
    0 F1,1 F2,2 F3,3 F4  )
)

ORDER BY DAY asc;

-- output
EMP_ID  DAY         F1      F2      F3      F4
4176    08-APR-2019 08:45   14:41   15:08   16:08
4176    09-APR-2019  -      08:55    -      15:34
```

Comment: sql la venum bro

Comment: added below the sql query as requested

Answer (score 1):

Following is on an oracle database.  So don't get confused by "from dual"  and leading with is simply to simulate the input data.  Also on oracle trunc(date_time) returns the date only portion.  First with which creates mydata is to simulate input.  Then next with gets f1f4 by taking absolute min/max by date.  Next computes f2 and f4 by saying that we only want those rows where dates don't match f1 and f4.  Per your rule either emp+dat has 2 or 4 rows.  Then final joins original source with these 2 to get f1,f2,f3,f4.  Distinct is because the driver is original

```
with mydata as (
    select '4176' emp_id, '3' eventid, to_date('2019-04-09 15:34:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from dual union all
    select '4176' emp_id, '1' eventid, to_date('2019-04-09 08:55:13', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from dual union all
    select '4176' emp_id, '3' eventid, to_date('2019-04-08 14:41:37', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from dual union all
    select '4176' emp_id, '2' eventid, to_date('2019-04-08 15:08:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from dual union all
    select '4176' emp_id, '1' eventid, to_date('2019-04-08 14:41:37', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from dual union all
    select '4176' emp_id, '0' eventid, to_date('2019-04-08 08:45:13', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from dual
),
getf1f4 as (
    select emp_id, trunc(dt) dt, count(*) num_rows, min(dt) f1, max(dt) f4
    from mydata
    group by emp_id, trunc(dt)
),
getf2f3 as (
    select ee.emp_id, getf1f4.dt,
           min(ee.dt) f2,
           max(ee.dt) f3
    from mydata ee join getf1f4 on ee.emp_id = getf1f4.emp_id and trunc(ee.dt) = getf1f4.dt
    where ee.dt not in ( getf1f4.f1, getf1f4.f4)
    group by ee.emp_id, getf1f4.dt
)
select distinct 
       ee.emp_id, getf1f4.dt, getf1f4.f1, getf2f3.f2, getf2f3.f3, getf1f4.f4
from mydata ee 
     join getf1f4 on ee.emp_id = getf1f4.emp_id and trunc(ee.dt) = getf1f4.dt
     left outer join getf2f3 on ee.emp_id = getf2f3.emp_id and trunc(ee.dt) = getf2f3.dt
```

Answer (score 1):

@dolu bolu

the requested sql query can be referred and altered from below query:

```
select emp_id, day, f1, f2, f3, f4  from 
(select a.emp_id,to_char(a.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY') day,
(select to_char(b.DT,'HH24:MI') from sample_event b where b.emp_id=a.emp_id and to_char(b.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY')=to_char(a.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY') and b.event_id=0 ) F1,
(select to_char(b.DT,'HH24:MI') from sample_event b where b.emp_id=a.emp_id and to_char(b.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY')=to_char(a.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY') and b.event_id=1 ) F2,
(select to_char(b.DT,'HH24:MI') from sample_event b where b.emp_id=a.emp_id and to_char(b.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY')=to_char(a.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY') and b.event_id=2 ) F3,
(select to_char(b.DT,'HH24:MI') from sample_event b where b.emp_id=a.emp_id and to_char(b.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY')=to_char(a.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY') and b.event_id=3 ) F4,
(select max(b.DT) from sample_event b where b.emp_id=a.emp_id and to_char(b.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY')=to_char(a.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY')  ) max_time,
(select min(b.DT) from sample_event b where b.emp_id=a.emp_id and to_char(b.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY')=to_char(a.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY')  ) min_time
from sample_event a group by a.emp_id,to_char(a.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
order by day;
```

you can use datediff function to get the hours between max_time and min_time